# Grouping data by ID from different CSV files

Tags: csv, apache-spark, rdd

I am having different kinds of data sets which are connected by the `ID` column.

File A

```
ID, x1, x2, x3
1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4
2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3
3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2
```

File B

```
ID, y1, y2, y3
1, A, T, T
2, G, A, C
3, C, A, G
```

File C

```
ID, z1, z2, z3
1, 34, 67, 49
2, 34, 56, 89
3, 23, 57, 87
```

This means, that for element with `ID = 1` I have

```
    x1, y1, z1
1: [0.5, A, 34]
```

and so on. So what I want to accomplish is to load the data given in `A.csv`, `B.csv` and `C.csv` and group everything by `ID` such that it's guaranteed that the data for any element resides on the same node.

How can I do that?

Comment: So did you encounter any particular problem with that? Just `join`...

Comment: as suggested by @zero323 please try to join like below answer, I tried to give more pointers. Hope that helps.

Comment: @zero323 : I was just wondering my below analysis of "broadcast join" is correct. Request your comments on my answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Question :***
> **So what I want to accomplish is to load the data given in A.csv, B.csv
> and C.csv and group everything by ID such that it's guaranteed that
> the data for any element resides on the same node.**
>
> ***How can I do that?***

---

> **Answer :**
>
> ***By default join is broadcast join (small data will be broadcasted(kind of replicated cache topology) to each node )***
>
> Please see below implementation (specially apply method)
> https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala

The above behaviour is controlled by `canBroadCast` method in the class above which uses below property `autoBroadCastJoinThreshHold`.

[image]

#### In your case see below code snippet where I used spark-csv + scala syntax

```
val testCSV1DF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/data/FileA.csv")
    val testCSV2DF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/data/FileB.csv")
    val testCSV3DF= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/data/FileC.csv")
 

    // here you can save each dataframe  in hive tables as well

    ### By default join is broadcast hash join (small data will be broadcasted(kind of replicated cache) to each node )
    val joinedDF1 = testCSV1DF.as('a').join(testCSV2DF.as('b'), testCSV1DF("a.Id") === testCSV2DF("b.Id")).select("ID", "x1", "x2", "x3","y1","y2","y3")
    
    joinedDF1.printSchema
    
    val finaljoinedDF = joinedDF1.as('ab').join(testCSV3DF.as('c'), joinedDF1("ab.Id") === testCSV3DF("c.Id")).select("ID", "x1", "x2", "x3","y1","y2","y3","z1","z2","z3")
    
    finaljoinedDF.printSchema
    finaljoinedDF.show
```

you can use `df.explain` to know what is going on...

Hope that helps!

Comment: do you have any issue implementing above?

Comment: @displayname: the question you asked is in-line with my answer or the question you intended to ask was totally different?

Comment: you have any issue implementing above?